# What is the minimum investment for Bitcoin?

Tags: investing, divisibility

I'm interested in how much money do I have to invest if I want to buy Bitcoins? Is there any minimum?

Comment: he factors that matter in order to give you the best answer include: Where are you located (country)?, how much are you looking to buy?, what payment methods do you have available?, how soon do you need access to the proceeds, is privacy important?

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. There's a perception that Bitcoin is a merely a security, so this question could serve as a way of dispelling that myth by explaining that there is no minimum investment like there can be for securities.

Answer (score 4):

On the whole, **there is no minimum investment for Bitcoin**, as it is not a security such as an ETF or mutual fund purchased through a brokerage or management firm.

What minimum purchases exist on Bitcoin exchanges are merely requirements set by each individual exchange to reflect the minimum purchase/sale that they feel is necessary to cover their overhead for each transaction.

Purchasing from an individual trader, you'll find that there is generally no such minimum, aside from whatever minimum they set to make it worth the time and travel expense for a rendezvous.

Answer (score 3):

Most exchanges have no minimum deposit however there are per-transaction fees which make smaller deposits uneconomical.

The cost to deposit funds varies based on each exchange and each country.